# 2 years data in 2 different tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to know what's the best way to store the data of current year(2024), and previous year(2023)  into two different tables. And these years have to be dynamic. Currently, I use these in where condition

`DATEDIFF('day',TEST_DATE,CURRENT_DATE) <= 365`

`TEST_DATE < dateadd(year, -1, current_date) AND TEST_DATE  > dateadd(year, -2, current_date)`

Comment: Smells like bad database design. Why do you want to separate the data in different tables in the first place? Use partitioning can be much more efficient.

Comment: So each day, you will some data in the "last year" table and some older data in the "prior year" table, but in 3 years time, both tables will have data for 3 different years. This is almost anti partitioning.. And makes so little sense. If you framed it more like: every day we make heaps of row, rows that are "recent" are valuable, and data with older time is low value, but we want to keep it any way. so are looking to use two tables to allow "high value" reports to just use the high value data. Then putting filters to have on two inserts or perhaps a multi-table insert makes sense.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=multi+table+insert#conditional-multi-table-inserts

Comment: It is NOT good practice to divide data like this across different tables.

Answer (score 2):

Using [multi table insert](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=multi%20table%20insert#conditional-multi-table-inserts)

some setup:

```
create table high_value(id number, val_date date, insert_date date);
create table low_value(id number, val_date date, insert_date date);

create or replace table new_data as
    select $1 as id, to_date($2, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as val_date from values
    (1,'2024/01/15'), -- high value
    (2,'2023/10/15'), -- high value
    (3,'2023/01/15'), -- low value
    (4,'2021/10/15') -- no value
;
```

we can then use the filters and push the data as we wish:

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN val_date >= dateadd('year', -1, CURRENT_DATE)  THEN
    INTO high_value
  WHEN val_date >= dateadd('year', -2, CURRENT_DATE) AND val_date < dateadd('year', -1, CURRENT_DATE) THEN
    INTO low_value
SELECT nd.*, CURRENT_DATE
from new_data as nd;
```

| number of rows inserted into HIGH_VALUE | number of rows inserted into LOW_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |

Answer (score -1):

It is **NOT** good practice to divide data like this across different tables. Using a WHERE clause similar (not the same!) to what is already shown, along with good indexing or partitioning, is the common accepted and good way to do this.

For the `WHERE` clause, the problem with what is shown is the first one performs a calculation across *every row in the table*, even rows you don't need, which also breaks any index use on that column. When you have the option, NEVER make the adjustment and row data... invert the predicate to act on the constant part of the expression instead, so this:

```
DATEDIFF('day',TEST_DATE,CURRENT_DATE) <= 365
```

becomes this:

```
DATEADD('day', -365, Current_date) < TEST_DATE
```

(note: I don't have a snowflake system handy and postive/negative datediff is something I have a mental block around have to look up or verify *every time*, so I may have the `>` sign backwards.) You probably also want to use a year, instead of 365 days.

Again, if you have indexed or partitioned the table well, this can perform *just as well* as splitting the data across two tables, and save you a lot of headaches later for cross-year queries.